# Implementing member access operator-> for ForwardIterator with on-the-fly computed temporary values

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

I'm implementing an iterator for an adaptor range which lazily evaluates something on an original range. This means: dereferencing the iterator should dereference the underlying iterator and apply some operation on the result, then returning the result of that operation.

```
T operator*() const {
    return someOperation(*original_iterator);
}
```

How can I implement `operator->` analogous to this `operator*`? When looking at other iterator's implementations, they usually return a `T*`. But I can't return a pointer, since the "pointed to object" is a temporary, computed on-the-fly.

What's the usual guidance in this case? May I simply return a `T` instead?

Although I personally don't need this operator (I could also use `(*i).m` instead of `i->m` and the standard algorithms don't seem to depend on `->` either), I'd like my iterator to **strictly conform** to the [`ForwardIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) concept which is a specialization of [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) which requires the implementation of this operator.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to just use Boost.Iterators to implement your iterators, which takes care of the tricky code.

But the technique used by Boost.Iterators isn't that complicated. It looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class proxy_holder {
  T t;
public:
  proxy_holder(const T& t) : t(t) {}
  T* operator ->() const { return &t; }
};

class the_iterator {
  // ...
  proxy_holder<my_proxy> operator ->() const {
    return proxy_holder<my_proxy>(**this);
  }
};
```

This relies on the fact that arrow operators get chained, i.e. if one arrow operator returns something that isn't a raw pointer, the arrow operator is called on that thing in turn, until you get to a pointer.

Comment: Yeah I already thought of that but thought that it might be possible to do it without a temporary copy. Is this an advantage over just holding `T t;` inside the iterator itself? My guess is yes, that the proxy will effectively be optimized away, i.e. the concern about the temporary copy is invalid. Can you confirm this?

Comment: always assume that the compiler will optimise away extra code. Humans understand clarity. Compilers understand optimisation.

Comment: I think it should be `T const * operator ->() const { return &t; }`

Comment: @neverlastn That depends on whether you want your pointer-like thing to have transitive constness or not. Most smart pointers don't, i.e. a `const std::unique_ptr<T>` doesn't mean you can't modify the T it points to.